# "Synchronize with repository" show conflicts that are not real conflicts

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

We're working with Eclipse and SVN. Sometimes when one member of the team performs a "Synchronize with repository", some files are marked with conflicts [image], but in reality there is not any conflict.

We're using SVNKit 1.8.14 r10627.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Also happens to me. After a while the files are not in conflict. Suppose this is an eclipse problem because of late refresh of svn information. Since your teammates must perform merge they will see there is no conflicts so...

Comment: What SVN plug-in do you use in Eclipse? Is it Subclipse or Subversive? Have you tried switching the SVN Connector to JavaHL instead of SVNKit? Start Eclipse and navigate to Window | Preferences | Team | SVN. Look for a setting to change the connector to JavaHL.

Comment: We're using Polarion Subversive SVN 1.8